# Null pointer while returning subclass image in superclass

Tags: java, image, exception, nullpointerexception, null

I'm trying to code space invaders and am getting a null pointer (very bottom of Entity class, triggers on getImageWidth() when trying to load the image for each entity. I realize this means the image file is null, I just can't figure out how to load it in correctly.

There are 3 entities: aliens, bullets, and the player. The entity class is supposed to grab all the information, and the subclasses call its method to load the image. I have a feeling this isn't right, but again, I'm not sure how else to go about it.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

public class Alien extends Entity implements Constants {
private File alienImageFile = new File(ALIEN_IMAGE_FILE_NAME);

public Alien(int x, int y) {
    this.setIsVisible(true);
    this.setx(x);
    this.sety(y);
    this.setdx(0);
    this.setdy(ALIEN_SPEED);
    this.setImageFromFile(alienImageFile);
}

//We don't want to reset the position of the alien if it goes out of bounds
public void checkHeightBounds() {
}
}
```

and

```
public class Entity implements Constants {
 private File defaultImageFile = new File(DEFAULT_IMAGE_FILE_NAME);
 private BufferedImage image;
 private int x;
 private int y;
 private int dx;
 private int dy;
 private int imageHeight;
 private int imageWidth;
 private boolean isVisible;


public void setImageHeight(int newImageHeight) {
    this.imageHeight = newImageHeight;
}

public void setImageWidth(int newImageWidth) {
    this.imageWidth = newImageWidth;
}

public int getdy() {
    return dy;
}

public BufferedImage getImage() { //this may not be safe
    return image;
}

public int getImageWidth() {
    if (!(this.getImage().equals(null))) {
        return this.getImage().getWidth();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }

public Entity(int x, int y) {
    this.setx(x);
    this.sety(y);
}
public void setImageFromFile(File file) {
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
}
```

I've removed some of the getters and setters for clarity.

Comment: i think you mean `this.getImage() != null` (or more concisely, `getImage() != null` -- you don't need to say`this...`)

Comment: `} catch (IOException e) { }` <- Don't leave catch blocks empty, this is probably telling you WHY the image is `null`